# How I can fetch textarea data to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, fetch

I cannot send data of  `<textarea>` to node js, Node js don't see the my sent data.

For Fetch data to Node Js

```
            continueBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
                console.log(myMsg.value)
                console.log(typeof(myMsg.value))

                const req = await fetch("/sendmsg", {method: "POST",body: myMsg.value}) ;
                console.log("Fetched")

            })
```

For get data in Node js

```
const {userMessage} = Object.keys(req.body)
```

Comment: you need to run `JSON.stringify()` on the data.

Comment: @chovy — That is insufficient (as per my answer a suitable content-type and matching body paring middleware is also needed, and the data needs to be wrapped in an object)

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a string to `body`. Since you aren't overriding it, it will be given a `text/plain` content-type.

On the server you expect `req.body` to contain an object.

You haven't shown us what, if any, body parsing middlewares you have configured in your server side code, but none of the common ones will convert something that is `text/plain` into an object.

You should:

- Make sure that you have a body parsing middleware configured
- Encode the data you are passing to `body` (e.g. with [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)) so it has name=value pairs instead of being a plain string.

If you end up passing a string (e.g. if you pass a string of JSON instead of a URLSearchParams object) then you'll also need to set a `Content-Type` request header that matches your data format.

Answer (score 0):

"`const {userMessage} = Object.keys(req.body)`"

I don't see why you'd be expecting to have a `userMessage` key in your body object with the code you pasted. It's possible the data is being passed properly, but you are trying to access the wrong key. I would try logging in your server code to debug the response format as a first step:
`console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))`

Let me know if that gets you enough help to move forward, and I can circle back here if not.

Comment: I try to send my form values to node js. But the value of textarea is seem undefined.

Comment: Check out @quentin's response. We need more information about your configuration for the node server in order to help you. This question doesn't have enough details for us to identify what the issue is. If you update the question to include your server configuration and more than one line of your server-side code, we can probably help you out.